# MVVMCross SQLite Community plugin won't add to Xamarin Studio project

Tags: sqlite, plugins, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm building a MVVMCross project, initially for iOS, but with a view to expanding onto Android. I'm using Xamarin Studio to create the app, and I have a PCL set up as my Core, with an iOS specific project for the UI, as per the examples in the docs and the excellent N+1 videos. However now I have hit a roadblock: I'm trying to add SQLite to the project from the NuGet packages, and per the recommendation I'm trying to add the Community plugin instead of the "old" version, but I get the following error when I do so:

```
        ------- Installing...MvvmCross.Community.Plugin.Sqlite 3.0.13 -------
    Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore (≥ 3.0.13)'.
    Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport (≥ 3.0.14)'.
    Adding 'MvvmCross.Community.Plugin.Sqlite 3.0.13' to ShimanoSocial.Core.
    Could not install package 'MvvmCross.Community.Plugin.Sqlite 3.0.13'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+wp80+win+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
    System.InvalidOperationException: Could not install package 'MvvmCross.Community.Plugin.Sqlite 3.0.13'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+wp80+win+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
      at NuGet.ProjectManager.ExtractPackageFilesToProject (IPackage package) [0x00000] in :0 
      at NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReferenceToProject (IPackage package) [0x00000] in :0 
      at NuGet.ProjectManager.Execute (NuGet.PackageOperation operation) [0x00000] in :0 
      at NuGet.ProjectManager.Execute (IPackage package, IPackageOperationResolver resolver) [0x00000] in :0 
      at NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReference (IPackage package, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) [0x00000] in :0 
      at NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReference (System.String packageId, NuGet.SemanticVersion version, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) [0x00000] in :0 
      at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.SharpDevelopPackageManager.AddPackageReference (IPackage package, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions) [0x00000] in :0 
      at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.SharpDevelopPackageManager.InstallPackage (IPackage package, ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.InstallPackageAction installAction) [0x00000] in :0 
      at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageManagementProject.InstallPackage (IPackage package, ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.InstallPackageAction installAction) [0x00000] in :0 
      at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.InstallPackageAction.ExecuteCore () [0x00000] in :0 
      at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.ProcessPackageAction.Execute () [0x00000] in :0 
      at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageActionRunner.Run (IPackageAction action) [0x00000] in :0 
      at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageViewModel.InstallPackage (IEnumerable`1 packageOperations) [0x00000] in :0 
      at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageViewModel.InstallPackage () [0x00000] in :0 
      at ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.PackageViewModel.TryInstallingPackage () [0x00000] in :0 
    ==============================
```

My project targets .NET 4.5+, WP8, W8, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS, using profile 78.

I have previously been able to install the "old" SQLite MVVMCross plugin but don't want to do this because it's apparently been deprecated in favour of the Community edition. However the Community edition won't install.

Can anyone please advise how to get this working?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this plugin.

Instead use the PCL nuget "sqlite.net pcl". It features a cross platform sqlite lib. You must at least add the nuget package to the final app (ios/android) project, and to the Core project.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/
or
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Async-PCL/ for the async version

Example use: https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL

In your startup method for each platform you have to register in mvvmcross IOC the ISQLitePlatform interface with the SQLitePlatformIOS implementation.

```
Mvx.RegisterType<ISQLitePlatform, SQLitePlatformIOS>();
```

Then you can create an instance of a SQLiteConnection by using the mvvmcross IOC builder.

```
var sqlConnection = Mvx.IocConstruct<SQLiteConnection>("mydbpath");
```

Or if you don't want to use the ioc, create a static property in your cross lib, then assign it at startup in each platform project.

NOTE: the IOC method is not supported, as mvvmcross IocContruct can not currently have parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Softlion for chipping in. I've installed the SQLite.Net PCL nuget package into both Core and platform-specific projects, but am stuck with how to use the PCL in my Core project. The connection seems to require an ISQLitePlatform object as its first parameter, but that doesn't make sense to me in the context of platform-agnostic PCL project. What haven't I understood correctly? I want to be able to use SQLite in my Core project and just call its API from the platform-specific projects. As far as the platform-specific projects are concerned they shouldn't even know that I'm using SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for that detail. I'll check the example as well and see if I can figure something out that will work in my case. Cheers!